# Render a partial in gem views folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, renderpartial

I'm writing a gem and I need that the app that use the gem could render a partial using  `= render "user_role_select"` from the `layout/application.html.haml`.

My `_user_role_select.html.haml` lives in the gem at the path `app/views/gem_name/`. When I'm calling the render I'm getting the followed message:

> Missing template /user_role_select with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html,
>   :builder, :ruby, :haml]}. Searched in:  * "/ruby-app/app/views"  *
>   "/bundle/gems/bootstrap-kaminari-views-0.0.5/app/views"  *
>   "/bundle/gems/kaminari-core-1.0.1/app/views"  * "/ruby-app"  * "/"

I'm noticed that the kaminari folder for example is included in the folders in which rails search so I'm guessing this is possible, but even looking in them source code I couldn't find any hint.

Comment: When you say "gem", is it a [Rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)? You will not be able to render the view, unless it's in an engine mounted by the application. You can't simply place the file in a special folder name.

Comment: @TomLord No is not an engine. Actually is not what I need an engine. I was  looking for a way to to add  my folder to the list of file 'Searched in'.

Comment: If it's not an engine, then it won't work (without some funny workaround, at least). Make it an engine.

Comment: @TomLord Doesn't an engine render an entire view despite just a partial? I still whant to use the main app application controller including some concernes.

Comment: By mounting an engine in the application, it will add the gem's `app/views` folder to the search paths. This is exactly what `bootstrap-kaminari-views` is doing, for example, which you can see in the error message. And yes, you can still use partials within engines.

Comment: @TomLord `bootstrap-kaminari-views` doesn't ask to mount the engine. I migrate all the functionality to an engine but still the view folder is not listed in the searched in folders. Since I don't need routes I didn't mount the engine in the `routes.rb`.

Comment: Would you like to re-post this question, with your rails engine solution? I see no reason why this solution would not work, so you must have something mis-configured.

Comment: Not all engines are mounted in routes.rb. Engines extend Rails. Think of it as a mini app inside your app.